# how to avoid loading the source for iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, iframe

I would like to improve loading performance for a page that has a button to trigger a popup initially hidden on the page (uses 'modal' component from twitter bootstrap). This popup body contains an iframe, which source is loaded on the page inital load adding about 30-40% more time to load, however. The iframe source is not needed to be loaded till the button is clicked which brings up the popup with the iframe. How can one avoid loading the iframe source on initial page load? ...only load the iframe source when the button is clicked? Can JS be used here? If so, then how or what method/library? Is there a better approach than make popup with iframe hidden in the page to improve loading time? Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with JavaScript (no extra libraries required).
Simply use a function to set the src/display the frame when a link or button is clicked.

```
function loadIFrame(frameID, url) {
    var frame = document.getElementById(frameID);
    frame.setAttribute('src', url);
    frame.style.display = 'block';
}
```

See the example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZNGmy/

Comment: Thank you Oscar...it works well. i used jquery library as following:

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#start-demo').bind("click", function(){
        var frame = $('#demo-frame');
        frame.attr('src', demoUrl);
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
});`

Answer (score 2):

Rather than having the pop-up as a hidden container that is made visible by the button, make the pop-up with the iframe content a separate html page that gets displayed by pressing the button. This way the content is not loaded until the button is pressed.

This link has an example of popping-up html pages.
http://allwebco-templates.com/support/S_add_pop.htm

Comment: Thank you jtmulls18. To avoid generating html pages, we went with Oscar approach, however, your approach may work well in future in different situation

Comment: Thank you latvian for the feedback.